# Pills with dropdown - make dropdown active

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am putting together a navigation bar. Here is the code:

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills">
  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/home">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i> Home
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/alerts">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bell"></i> Alerts
  </a>
  <div role="presentation" class="dropdown">

    <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
      role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Settings
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And Fiddle:
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/y8khqmo1/)

How can I make settings looks active when I select something from the dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the hard-coded "active" class from the first pill and add some JS logic:

```
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
const settings = document.getElementById('settings');

for(var item of navItems) {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
       for(let item of navItems) item.classList.remove('active');
       e.target.classList.add('active');
    });
}
```

Comment: lol I've just looked at your profile, it's probably a joke!  I don't think you can achieve this without JS anyways.

Comment: Your code works fine. Except that I had to add 'var' for item in the for loop. I modified the code. Thanks for help.